# Unity SolidGeometryLib sgObject initialization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently bought the SolidGeometryLib plugin from Unity Asset Store to do mesh boolean for my project and am trying to use my own GameIbject with my custom .obj file. I tried initializing the sgObject to do mesh boolean on them with following code but it fails with null point exception. Could anybody give me some help where I am getting it wrong?

```
 void initGameObjectAsSGObject() {
        GameObject skullGameObject = GameObject.Find("Skull");
        Mesh mesh = skullGameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        var verts = mesh.vertices;
        float[] vertices = new float[verts.Length * 3];
        Debug.Log(verts[0].x);
        foreach (Vector3 vertex in verts) {
            vertices.Append(vertex.x);
            vertices.Append(vertex.y);
            vertices.Append(vertex.z);
        }
        int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
        Debug.Log(triangles[10]);
        // Skull
        IntPtr pnts = sg_array_create_points();
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i += 3)
            sg_array_add_point(pnts, vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], vertices[i + 2]);
        IntPtr indxs = sg_array_create_int(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++)
            sg_array_add_int(indxs, triangles[i]);
        
        IntPtr customMeshObj = sg_object_custom_mesh(pnts, indxs);
        Debug.Log(customMeshObj);
        if (customMeshObj == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Debug.Log("customMeshObj is null");
            return;
        }
        skullGameObject.AddComponent<sgObject>().InitObject(customMeshObj);
        skullGameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        
        sg_array_free_points(pnts);
        sg_array_free_int(indxs);
    }
```

and this is the code the seller provided to create custom mesh.

```
public void AddCustomMesh()
        {
            float[] vertexes = {
             0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f,                        //  v1
             1.788854f, 0.000000f, 0.894427f,         //  v2  
             0.552786f, 1.701302f, 0.894427f,         //  v3
             -1.447214f, 1.051462f, 0.894427f,        //  v4
             -1.447214f, -1.051462f, 0.894427f,       //  v5
             0.552786f, -1.701302f, 0.894427f,        //  v6
             1.447214f, 1.051462f, -0.894427f,        //  v7
             -0.552786f, 1.701302f ,-0.894427f,       //  v8
             -1.788854f, 0.000000f, -0.894427f,       //  v9
             -0.552786f, -1.701302f, -0.894427f,      //  v10
             1.447214f, -1.051462f, -0.894427f,       //  v11
             0.0f,       0.0f, -2.0f };               //  v12 

            int[] icosahedron_indexes = {
                 2, 0, 1,       //  triangle 1
                 3, 0, 2,       //  triangle 2
                 4, 0, 3,       //  triangle 3
                 5, 0, 4,       //  triangle 4
                 1, 0, 5,       //  triangle 5
                 2, 1, 6,       //  triangle 6
                 7, 2, 6,       //  triangle 7
                 3, 2, 7,       //  triangle 8
                 8, 3, 7,       //  triangle 9
                 4, 3, 8,       //  triangle 10
                 9, 4, 8,       //  triangle 11
                 5, 4, 9,       //  triangle 12
                 10, 5, 9,      //  triangle 13
                 6, 1, 10,      //  triangle 14
                 1, 5, 10,      //  triangle 15
                 6, 11, 7,      //  triangle 16
                 7, 11, 8,      //  triangle 17
                 8, 11, 9,      //  triangle 18
                 9, 11, 10,     //  triangle 19
                 10, 11, 6      //  triangle 20
             };


            GameObject cmO = new GameObject("CustomMesh");

            float randRad = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.9f, 3.5f);

            IntPtr pnts = sg_array_create_points();
            for (int i = 0; i < vertexes.Length; i += 3)
                sg_array_add_point(pnts, vertexes[i] * randRad, vertexes[i + 1] * randRad, vertexes[i + 2] * randRad);

            IntPtr indxs = sg_array_create_int();
            for (int i = 0; i < icosahedron_indexes.Length; i++)
                sg_array_add_int(indxs, icosahedron_indexes[i]);

            IntPtr customMeshObj = sg_object_custom_mesh(pnts, indxs);

            sg_array_free_points(pnts);
            sg_array_free_int(indxs);

            if (customMeshObj == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(cmO);
                return;
            }

            randomTransform(customMeshObj);
            cmO.AddComponent<sgObject>().InitObject(customMeshObj);
            cmO.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        }
```

Comment: at what point exactly do you get the exception? in general why do you copy the vertices into a float array if then anyway you always need to pass all three components on? Couldn't you just iterate the `verts` directly instead just to reduce complexity a bit? ;)

Comment: @derHugo I'm getting the error(which exactly isn't an error but failure) at the if statement customMeshObj == IntPtr.Zero. And this library requires me to map Vector3 arrays to float array. I'll add sample code they made for creating custom mesh.

Comment: I don't see where the library requires you to use a float array .... you are anyway passing them in one by one in `sg_array_add_point(pnts, vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], vertices[i + 2]);` as three individual floats .. that's what I mean seems redundant, instead of the first loop where you move Vector3 components into the array you could as well directly forward them to your library at that point already